# Magento Add Catalog Discount to Bundle Products

Tags: php, magento

I have one bundle product and i want to add discount on bundle product for registered users.

so once user login they can see discount

or

once user login belongs to specific group can see and add to cart products with discount percentage.

is this possible.

Thanks

Comment: Was my answer useful? Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a special price for a single product based on customer group by the in-built `Group Price` function:

- Go to your product, to the `Prices` tab.
- Add Group Price
- Choose customer group `General` or any other you want.
- Set price, save and flush cache

Comment: Hi Gerard i have same problem its not working for me.